# ayuda con query

Tags: postgresql-9.3

me pueden colaborar, necesito que si es "numero_caida" o " diferencia" me cobre los mismo, gracias por la atención brindada

```
 ,CASE
        WHEN tp.numero_caida >= diferencia
            THEN diferencia
                ELSE tp.numero_caida 
           END 
     AS min_cancelar

,CASE
            WHEN tp.nombre_marcada = 'Albeiro'
                THEN tp.numero_caida * 10000
            WHEN tp.nombre_marcada = 'La Y'
                    THEN tp.numero_caida * 10000
            WHEN tp.numero_caida >=1
                THEN numero_caida * 5000
            ELSE 0
          END 
          AS cancelar
```

Comment: cuesta entender bien cual es la problemática

Comment: Saludos Jhonny, bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero que al momento de redactar preguntas, revises https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y tengas en mente lo siguiente "¿cómo debería escribir la pregunta para que sea entendible y que la gente del sitio pueda ayudarme a solucionar?", Entre más detalles, mejor :D

Comment: muchas gracias ya redacto bien la pregunta :D